# How do you hyphenate 'branches'?

Tags: hyphenation, syllables

How do you hyphenate the word 'branches'? I'm intrigued between `branch·es` and `bran·ches`.

Comment: /bræn-ʃəz/. Or you could hyphenate between C and H. Hyphenation is not yet an exact science.

Comment: `branch·es` isn’t very good hyphenation practice as far as I know it, since `branch` is also a word.

Comment: @minitech: Of course, *bran* is also a word, so by that token *bran-ches* would also be ruled out.  I have never before heard of this practice for hyphenation; do you have a reference?

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't.

It is only eight letters long, and is the produced plural of a word that is only six letters long, monosyllabic and from a single root, without suffix or prefix or compound parts.

As such, I'd move the entire word onto the next line, even when space was limited.

I note that [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/branch) and [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/branch), two dictionaries that contain hyphenation advice, both suggest that *branch* has no hyphenation opportunities. *Branches* of course only adds the *-es* of the plural, and one would never hyphenate at that point if at all avoidable.

If space was *extremely* limited, then such an unusual typographic situation would make this a matter of graphic design rather than normal typography, so the exact opposite would apply; I'd hyphenate it whichever way worked best visually with the rest of the graphic design. (In theory anyway, I'm not very skilled in such matters).

If I had a gun to my head and had to hyphenate the word as best I could, I'd probably do so as *bran·ches* to match the syllables and to avoid breaking on the *-es*, but I wouldn't be happy with it.

Comment: [Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/branching) hyphenates *punch-ing bag* after the "ch". So presumably the correct hyphenation would be *branch-es*, which isn't a good idea since *-es* is only two letters.