# How do you divide the syllables of plurals whose singular ends in "-e"?

Tags: hyphenation, syllables

How do you divide the syllables of plurals whose singular ends in "-e"?

For example, is "fences" "fen-ces" or "fenc-es"?
Is "appliances" "ap-pli-an-ces" or "ap-pli-anc-es"?

The context is not linguistic theory, but publishing. It is for my work as a copyeditor in a magazine. Somebody suggested using a dictionary, but if Webster's was clear on this, I wouldn't be bothering you with the question.

Comment: A dictionary will help.

Comment: What is the context for dividing these words? Are you asking about syllabification in terms of linguistic theories about pronunciation, or about typographical conventions about hyphenation? Hyphens aren't always put in places that linguists consider to be syllable boundaries.

Comment: I'm guessing it would be hard to come up with a reliable rule, without getting into a lot of depressing details.  I would generally go with "fen-ces", but "appliances" could go either way, depending on how fast it's spoken and the adjacent words.

Comment: Actually, the dictionary does NOT help. Thanks for you not helping either.

Comment: With regard to the second question, the context is not about linguistic theory, but about publishing. How to deal with this difficulty when correcting galley sheets as a copyeditor.

Comment: Hot Licks is quite right. It is hard to come up with a reliable rule; that's why I ask the question. I've been dealing with this for years in my work and haven't been able to come up with anything. I would agree that "fen-ces" seems better because when you pronounce the word, that's how word sounds. But it's not always so obvious. Perhaps the rule would be just that: however the word sounds when spoken. But perhaps someone else has a better answer.

Comment: @H. Dashner: if you are trying to decide whether you should break a line at applianc-es or applian-ces, ***don't use either one.*** They both look bad. It's just two or three letters. You should be able to either fit them on the same line with the *applian-* part, or break it at *appli-ances*. For confirmation, the TeX typesetting software, which usually knows what it's doing when it comes to hyphenation, gives *ap-pli-ances* as the possible hyphenation points.

Comment: (1) You talk about words that end with “e”, but then you show two examples that end with “nce”.  Is your question specifically about words that end with “nce”, or are there others?   (2) Microsoft Word also has a hyphenation function.  (And it says that “appliances” should be split as “ap·pli·ances”, with no break in the last five letters.)

Comment: Thanks for the edits! I don't know whether you're aware of this already, but some people follow a rule of not breaking a word across lines into parts that are less than three letters long (mentioned in the following posts: [American Luke's answer to "Breaking last word in the lines"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/85038/breaking/85039#85039?noredirect=1&lq=1); the hunspell system mentioned in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/458817?noredirect=1&lq=1)). This would support Peter Shor's comment saying that it is preferable to split at an earlier syllable break.

Comment: Another related question: [How do you hyphenate 'branches'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177167)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to decide whether you should break a line at *applianc-es* or *applian-ces,* don't use either one. They both look bad.

It's just two or three letters. You should generally be able to either fit them on the same line with the *applianc-* part, or break the word *appli-ances.* For confirmation, the TeX typesetting software, which usually knows what it's doing when it comes to hyphenation, gives *ap-pli-ances* as the possible hyphenation points.

By analogy with the *-er* and *-ing* endings, the appropriate hyphenation would be *applianc-es*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fencing) hyphenates *fencing* as *fenc-ing* and *silencer* as *si-lenc-er*. But the suffix *-es* is only two letters, so it usually shouldn't be necessary to break before it.  And if we believe the TeX typesetting software, it generally isn't done.

Answer (score 0):

A number of rules are standard for hyphenation with full-justified margins. The short answer is that you should never end up with *-es* when splitting lines, but segments of three letters or more are possible. My advice is mostly to ignore the effect of the plural on the word.

Guidelines may vary from house to house. Here is one example from the *[Handbook of Technical Writing](https://www.macmillanlearning.com/Catalog/product/handbookoftechnicalwriting-twelfthedition-alred)*, 12th ed., "hyphen" (p.239):

> Hyphens are also used to divide words at the end of a line, especially for full-justified margins within small columns. The following are standard guidelines for using hyphens to divide words at the end of lines:
>
> - Do not divide one-syllable words.
> - Divide words at syllable breaks, which you can determine with a dictionary.
> - Do not divide a word if only one letter would remain at the end of a line or if fewer than three letters would start a new line.
> - Do not divide a word at the end of a page; carry the word over to the next page.
> - If a word already has a hyphen in its spelling, divide the word at the existing hyphen.
> - Do not use a hyphen to break a URL or an e-mail address at the end of a line.

The first three bullet points are essential. No, you don't break up one syllable words. Yes, you can determine syllabification with a dictionary. No, you don't leave a two-letter segment at the start of the next line. Combined, these adjudicate examples like *appliance*:

- Pick a dictionary you'll use consistently (here I'll use [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appliances); for your purposes pick whichever you feel is consistent and in line with your purposes)
- Observe the syllabic breakdown of the singular form (ap·​pli·​ance)
- Break at a point that leaves at least three letters at the end and more than one letter at the start (ap-pliance or appli-ance)

One other guideline could help you choose between the two options. If you have a choice, it's practical to include enough of the word to provide clues as to pronunciation and thus what the resulting word will be. (Editor Andy Hollandbeck [puts it like this](https://www.copyediting.com/end-of-line-hyphenation-breaking-up-is-hard-to-do/#.XOaMDsSM-Uk): "A reader should intuitively understand how to pronounce the first part of a broken word without knowing the rest of the word.") *ap-* could end in *apiary* or *appliance*, which would change the *a* a lot, so *appli-* gives more information on how to pronounce the resulting word.

What would change with the plural form? Here, you need change nothing. You already have one or two acceptable break points, so making a decision on the plural is unnecessary. *Appli-ances* is fine. For most words, the "s" doesn't make a meaningful change, especially if the word is longer than two syllables. You will already have viable options.

If you adopted this measure, then though *fences* is two syllables and could theoretically be broken up in accord with the previous rules (*fen·ces*), because the singular word is one syllable and wouldn't be broken up, you can decide not to break it up either. (Is one character truly that crucial?)

The possible exceptions to these rules are rare, but crop up with two-syllable words where the plural form results in a three-syllable word. With a word like [cadence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cadence) (*ca·dence*), the plural (*ca·den·ces*) invites a possible choice between guidelines. Do you go with the break-down that gives more information about the pronunciation of vowels (since for *ca-* the result can involve a soft or hard *a*), or do you stick with *ca-* because it is in line with other guidelines in the singular? The latter is simpler, but the former gives you slightly more flexibility.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure how to answer all of you (technically speaking). This is the third time I'm writing my answer. Here goes...

Comment: I wanted to thank TaliesinMerlin, who took the matter seriously and send a thoughtful response, as well as @sumelic for supplying useful references. I will take the considerations into account in my work and will check out all references supplied. Thank you for your time.